# Building Alamofire 1.3.1 using Carthage fails

Tags: xcode, swift, alamofire, osx-yosemite, carthage

I have been facing an issue that fails to build Alamofire using Carthage.

My environment is as follows :

- OSX 10.10.5
- Xcode 6.4

  - Also 7.0 and 7.1 are already installed.
- Carthage 0.9.3
- Trying to install Alamofire 1.3.1 (latest Swift 1.2 release)

I tried the command below then error occurs.

```
$ echo 'github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "1.3.1"' > Cartfile ; carthage update --platform ios
*** Cloning Alamofire
*** Checking out Alamofire at "1.3.1"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/ch/jcgf09f15hl391jn849d5yr80000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.ZM1b0b.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alamofire-fmnpbxqgrcncdhbtipavvywlxagy/Build/Intermediates/Alamofire.build/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Alamofire normal arm64
(1 failure)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
A shell task failed with exit code 65:
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alamofire-fmnpbxqgrcncdhbtipavvywlxagy/Build/Intermediates/Alamofire.build/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Alamofire normal arm64
(1 failure)
```

Then I tried to build using Xcode.

Open `Alamofire.xcworkspace` and hit Cmd+B then fails with error below :

[Xcode error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC4dx.png)

I have never seen the warning `Unable to find swiftCore; please set SWIFT_LIBRARY_PATH (currentry '') to the folder containing swiftCore`

I think that this warning relates to the issue, but I don't know how to solve this one...

Are there any solutions?